# Openflow Extension for OMNET++

Tags: omnet++, veins, openflow, sumo

I am using omnet++ 5.5.1, veins-5a2, and sumo 1.2.0. Which openflow version does omnet++ support? And from where i can download it?

Please help me. thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is an OpenFlow port at : https://github.com/inet-framework/openflow
I'm not sure but my guess is that it's just 1.0

Comment: thank you. And what about Simulte? i did not found any version of simulte for omnet++ 5.5.1 or omnet++ 5.4.1

Comment: There will be a new release in a few days, but the master branch on GitHub already world fine with inet 3.6 and the latest omnet.